# hand-coded table name works but dynamic name is not working in PHP

Tags: php

This is the code That is supposed to delete the student from the table.
but it it not working.
it only works when the table name is static.

```
public function delete_student($student_class,$school_session,$id){
    $table_name = $student_class."_".$school_session."_student_record";
    $pdo = KITE::getInstance('pdo');
    $query = $pdo->prepare("DELETE FROM ".$table_name." WHERE `id` = ?");
    $query->bindValue(1,$id);
    $query->execute();

}
```

Comment: Print table name and check if it is equal to static one.

Comment: Looks to me like a **horrific** database design has come home to roost

Comment: @pupil, i have printed it. it is equal to the static one.

Comment: could you post an example of what the table name looks like in all it's gory glory

Comment: @RiggsFolly, I am still a learner, I'm willing to improve. please, why is it horrific?

Comment: @RamRaider it is supposed to return `class1_2014/2015_student_record`  where $class= class1 and $session=2014/2015.

Comment: I'm fairly sure that a slash is not allowed in a table name! 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifiers.html

Comment: Any reason why you don't just have 1 table, with `student_class` and `school_session` columns instead?

Comment: It doesn't look like there is any normalisation going on - would be nice to see the schema

Comment: @Ivar, i dont understand. Are you saying it will be better to have a table with a with  a name `school_details` with two column `student_class` and `school_session`. if that is the case, how will i hand a attach a `school_session` with a multiple classes. I don't know if you understand

Comment: You can use a select, and use the where to select the classes: `SELECT * FROM school_details WHERE student_class = 'class1' AND school_session = '2014/2015';`

Comment: @RamRaider, what is happening is that I'm designing a school portal. The admin will select a `class`  and `session` to display the students in the particular class. when the student list has come up, the admin can select a student and delete such student from the database based on the `student class` and `student_session`. 
That is why I'm grabbing the student `student class` and `student_session`. 
Is there a better to get this done?

Comment: In a word, Yes. Proper database design would save you a lot of trouble in the future - the aim of the game is to reduce or eliminate redundant data in a database ( normalisation ) and to structure your schema in such a way as to allow easy access to recrds and also easy administration of these records. Judging by the code given above you would keep adding tables, with these rather unusual names for each year the db is used and also for each class. I'll post a quickly constructed demo database for you to play around with if you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in a comment, a slash `/` is not permitted in the name of a table, column, function name, procedure name etc. Why then your query works when the name is statically typed is a mystery.

A quickly constructed demo that uses `innodb` tables with `foreign keys` and hopefully very little / no redundancy. If you have mysql running locally try running this in your gui ( such as [heidi](http://www.heidisql.com/download.php) ) to get an idea of how it might be accomplished.

```
drop database if exists `demo_school_sessions`;
create database if not exists `demo_school_sessions`;
use `demo_school_sessions`;


drop table if exists `classes`;
create table if not exists `classes` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned not null auto_increment,
  `class` varchar(50) not null,
  primary key (`id`)
) engine=innodb default charset=latin1;

insert into `classes` (`id`, `class`) values
    (1, 'mathematics'),
    (2, 'physics'),
    (3, 'computing');


drop table if exists `sessions`;
create table if not exists `sessions` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned not null auto_increment,
  `session` varchar(50) not null,
  primary key (`id`)
) engine=innodb default charset=latin1;

insert into `sessions` (`id`, `session`) values
    (1, 'summer'),
    (2, 'winter'),
    (3, 'spring'),
    (4, 'autumn');

drop table if exists `students`;
create table if not exists `students` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned not null auto_increment,
  `student` varchar(50) not null,
  primary key (`id`)
) engine=innodb default charset=latin1;

insert into `students` (`id`, `student`) values
    (1, 'bobby droptables'),
    (2, 'sue select'),
    (3, 'david delete'),
    (4, 'valerie view'),
    (5, 'peter procedure'),
    (6, 'freddy function');

drop table if exists `year`;
create table if not exists `year` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned not null auto_increment,
  `year` varchar(9) not null default '2014/2015',
  primary key (`id`)
) engine=innodb default charset=latin1;

insert into `year` (`id`, `year`) values
    (1, '2014/2015'),
    (2, '2015/2016'),
    (3, '2016/2017'),
    (4, '2017/2018'),
    (5, '2018/2019'),
    (6, '2019/2020');

drop table if exists `master`;
create table if not exists `master` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned not null auto_increment,
  `student` int(10) unsigned not null default '0',
  `class` int(10) unsigned not null default '0',
  `session` int(10) unsigned not null default '0',
  `year` int(10) unsigned not null default '0',
  primary key (`id`),
  key `student` (`student`),
  key `class` (`class`),
  key `session` (`session`),
  key `year` (`year`),
  constraint `fk_year` foreign key (`year`) references `year` (`id`) on delete cascade on update cascade,
  constraint `fk_class` foreign key (`class`) references `classes` (`id`) on delete cascade on update cascade,
  constraint `fk_session` foreign key (`session`) references `sessions` (`id`) on delete cascade on update cascade,
  constraint `fk_stud` foreign key (`student`) references `students` (`id`) on delete cascade on update cascade
) engine=innodb default charset=latin1;

insert into `master` (`id`, `student`, `class`, `session`, `year`) values
    (1, 1, 3, 4, 1),
    (2, 1, 1, 4, 1),
    (3, 2, 2, 4, 1),
    (4, 2, 3, 4, 1);


/* example to select records */
select * from `master` m
  left outer join `students` s on s.id=m.student
  left outer join `classes` c on c.id=m.class
  left outer join `sessions` ss on ss.id=m.`session`
  left outer join `year` y on y.id=m.`year`
where m.`class`=3 or m.`student`=1;

/* Example to delete a student */
delete from `students` where `id`=1;


/*

*/
```

Because of `Foreign Key Dependencies` if you delete a student from the student table all associated records from the `master` table would also be deleted as there is a `cascade` set for both `update` and `delete`. Care MUST be taken when using `foreign keys` like this because if you delete a record accidentally and there is a cascaded delete set on the key then all the associated records disappear!

Comment: Wow quite some effort you put into this answer. Hope you dont mind, I did a minor edit so that it would run `out of the box`, just removed the `auto_increment` and moved the `master` table definition to the last table created as all the Foriegn keys stuff wont work if the other tables are not created first. Gets a plus 1 from me just for effort. I hope the guy can appreciate all the effort

Comment: Good call@RiggsFolly - hope it helps the OP get the gist of how better to structure a db...

Comment: I somehow doubt it, but we live in hope.

Comment: Thanks @RamRaider . I just gained a new concept on how to interact with database tables. Thanks for your effort. I really appreciate.

Comment: @RiggsFolly, Thanks for your addition. Thanks your time too.

Comment: @AransiolaOluwaseun It would be nice if you rewarded Ram's efforts with an UPVOTE

Comment: @RiggsFolly, i have done that since. What i see is this 
 "Thanks for the feedback! Once you earn a total of 15 reputation, your votes will change the publicly displayed post score."